# How to map foreign key relationship in hibernate using just primary key column and not the entire entity?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations, hibernate-entitymanager

I want to achieve something like this where A_id is a foreign key to A.

```
@Entity
Class A {
  @Id
  private long id
}

@Entity
Class B {
  @Id
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private long A_id;
}
```